# Sequence with two restrictions

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does there exist a positive sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=3}^\infty$ that satisfies both of the following conditions?

1. $\sum_{k=3}^n\frac{a_k}{k}\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.
2. $\frac{\sum_{k=3}^n a_k\sqrt{\frac{\log\log k}{k}}}{\sum_{k=3}^n a_k^2}\not\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

For (2), I don't mind if it converges to a non-zero value, fluctuates, or diverges to infinity, as long as it doesn't converge to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that works. Whatever has happened before (for $n<N_1$, say), we can always make the ratio from (2) large at some later point $N_2$ by taking $a_n=\epsilon$ very small on a very long subsequent interval $N_1\le n\le N_2$. More precisely, we need to choose $\epsilon, N_2$ such that $\epsilon (N_2\log\log N_2)^{1/2}\gg \max\{ 1, \sum_{n<N_1} a_n^2\}$ but $\epsilon N_2^{1/2}\lesssim 1$.

Of course, this doesn't stop us from also satisfying (1). For example, we can make $a_k=k$ every once in a while.